# How to automatically publish a console app to folder within csproj after compilation

Tags: .net, publish, csproj

I've got a csproj to create an .NET 6.0 app that I also wish to publish to a folder (linux-x64). I've created a profile but I don't know how to use this profile from within the csproj. I've read a lot of comments saying "dotnet .../p:PublishProfile..." I understand the concept but want I want is to have this automatized within the csproj and don't know how to write it in XML.
Anybody could help (with an example would be perfect).

**Final answer was to put this directly inside the csproj (as suggested by Anthony), it works great and as Anthony said "do not forget --no-build":**

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
  <RuntimeIdentifiers>linux-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
  <Exec Command="dotnet publish -p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile --no-build" />
</Target>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a PostBuildEvent through Visual Studio,[image] or simply by editing your project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x64;linux-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="dotnet publish -p:PublishSingleFile=true -r linux-x64 --framework net6.0 --self-contained -p:EnableCompressionInSingleFile=true -p:PublishTrimmed=true --no-build" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

Make sure you have linux-x64 in your RuntimeIdentifiers, and that you specify --no-build on the command

Comment: Thank you Anthony. I'm using a profile and changed your target by   <Exec Command="dotnet publish -p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile --no-build" /> and it works perfectly (by the way many many thanks for the tip to NOT FORGET "--no-build", I did first and the process started to build endlessly)